# MAUI ImageButton Doesn't Display Images

Tags: .net-6.0, maui

The Image tag renders the SVG file properly whereas the ImageButton doesn't.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<ImageButton Margin="0,10,10,10" Padding="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="0" Source="cart_dark.png"  HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24" />
<ImageButton Margin="0,10,10,10" Padding="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="0" Source="save_dark.png" HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24"/>
<ImageButton Margin="0,10,10,10" Padding="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="0" Source="settings_dark.png" HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24"/>

       

 <Image Margin="0,10,10,10" Source="cart_dark.png"  HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24"/>
 <Image Margin="0,10,10,10" Source="save_dark.png" HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24"/>
 <Image Margin="0,10,50,10" Source="settings_dark.png" HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24"/>
```

[image]

Comment: As a test, what displays if you specify `<ImageButton ... IsOpaque="True" />`? Another test, `<ImageButton ... BackgroundColor="Pink" />`?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Background color shows up.  IsOpaque didn’t have any effect.  Made the button larger as well to no avail!

Comment: 1) Are these single color pngs? Test with some small full-color bitmap. [Though shouldn't matter once its in memory. Trying to think of anything.] 2) In what container? Nested layouts or toolbar or nav bar? Maybe a bug related to container layout. [Though with explicit H/WRequests, I don't expect that.] Test these on a ContentPage, that contains only a StackLayout Orientation=Horizontal, with these in that StackLayout.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I will try the SVGs in a sample app & upload the same.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve These are in StackLayout Orientation=“Horizontal”… Icons are from MetroStudio 5 exported as SVG.

Comment: **3)** Is there a `Style` declaration for either `Image` or `ImageButton`? Either on page or in App.xaml? [Trying to think of anything that might cause the two to behave differently.]  **4)** If you load one of the `.png` files in a **paint** software, what are its dimensions in **pixels**? **5)** They were "exported as SVG", yet the file names end in `.png`? That doesn't sound reliable. OR did you then run it through a utility to make android resource files (which would be .pngs)? **6)** Are you testing on Windows, iOS, or Android?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. I haven't found a solution yet, but as a temporary workaround you can place an Image behind the ImageButton

```
<Grid>
  <Image Margin="0,10,10,10" Source="cart_dark.png"  HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24"/>
  <ImageButton Margin="0,10,10,10" Padding="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="0" Source="cart_dark.png"  HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24" />
</Grid>

<Grid>
  <Image Margin="0,10,10,10" Source="save_dark.png" HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24"/>
  <ImageButton Margin="0,10,10,10" Padding="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="0" Source="save_dark.png" HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24"/>
</Grid>

<Grid>
  <Image Margin="0,10,50,10" Source="settings_dark.png" HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24"/>
  <ImageButton Margin="0,10,10,10" Padding="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="0" Source="settings_dark.png" HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24"/>
</Grid>
```

The Image will be visable behind the ImageButton while the ImageButton remains clickable.

ps: For those wondering about the png ending for the svg files: If you use the svg ending the image will not be displayed, while it will be with the png ending even though its an svg. If you look at a new Maui project you will see that they did the same in the template for the dotnet_bot.svg image.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. If I were to use "Image" in both XAML and code-behind, everything would render correctly. However, once I start using "ImageButton" XAML renders correctly however the code-behind does not respect the "Aspect" property. Your approach is a good band-aid, but hoping for a more permanent solution from the MAUI team.

Answer (score 0):

- Too big SVG Width/Height (in view box or self size of path)
- Header problem. Try open in editor and save again (etc Adobe Illustrator, Gravit Designer)

Comment: The SVGs are exported from MetroStudio and display in the Image tag just fine.  I can attach them here if it’d help.

Comment: @VyasBharghava try set size 24x24 pixels for svg image

Answer (score 0):

If you select the build action to be MauiIcon for the image or icon you want to use for the button, Maui will generate a .ico file located in the build after compilation.

```
<ImageButton Source = Margin="0,10,10,10" Padding="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="0" Source="cart_dark.ico"  HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that iOS is case sensitive but Windows isn't so putting everything in lower case fixed it for me.

Comment: do yo men below worked for you?

<imagebutton source = margin="0,10,10,10" padding="0,0,0,0" cornerradius="0" source="cart_dark.ico"  heightrequest="24" widthrequest="24"/>